# how to bind the enum types of dropdown to the Dropdown list?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint-2010

```
public enum CandidateStatus : int {

    None = 0,

    Invalid = 1,

    [Microsoft.SharePoint.Linq.ChoiceAttribute(Value="Pending Approval")]
    PendingApproval = 2,

    [Microsoft.SharePoint.Linq.ChoiceAttribute(Value="Open")]
    Open = 4,

    [Microsoft.SharePoint.Linq.ChoiceAttribute(Value="Screening")]
    Screening = 8,

    [Microsoft.SharePoint.Linq.ChoiceAttribute(Value="Interviewing")]
    Interviewing = 16,

    [Microsoft.SharePoint.Linq.ChoiceAttribute(Value="Offers Issued")]
    OffersIssued = 32,

    [Microsoft.SharePoint.Linq.ChoiceAttribute(Value="Hired")]
    Hired = 64,

    [Microsoft.SharePoint.Linq.ChoiceAttribute(Value="Cancelled")]
    Cancelled = 128,
}
```

this is my enum code in linq.cs file.

Here CandidateStatus is the choice column which is defined in Sharepoint list.
how can i bind this choice field of "CandidateStatus" in dropdown list and how can i insert this selected dropdown value into the Sharepoint list?
Can you anyone help on this please......

Answer (score 2):

I think your only option is to map the enum values to an object:

```
myDropDown.TextField = "Value";
myDropDown.ValueField = "ID";

myDropDown.DataSource = ((CandidateStatus []) Enum.GetValues(typeof(CandidateStatus))
   .Select(c => new {
                      ID = (int)c, 
                      Value = ( typeof(CandidateStatus)
                       .GetField(c.ToString())
                       .GetCustomAttributes(
                         typeof(Microsoft.SharePoint.Linq.ChoiceAttribute), false) 
                           as EnumStringValueAttribute[]).FirstOrDefault() 
                        ?? c.ToString()
                    });
myDropDown.DataBind();
```

Comment: thanks for you reply...This is the code which is used to bind the enum values into dropdown and also need to know how this binded values are get stored in sharepoint list when button is clicked? Any idea  about this?